# Mod_rewrite rule for /login to login.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Somebody knows a rule which transforms `http://domain/login` to `http://domain/login.php`? I want it specifically so I can assign also http://domain/loginplease to http://domain/login.php and also http://domain/login to http://domain/login1.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule ^/login$ /login.php [L]

What did you try? This is hardly a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /loginplease [NC, OR]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /login.php [L]
```